# fpdf - How do I separate data into 3 columns?

Tags: php, fpdf

I have tried `foreach`, functions, and `array_chunk` but I just cannot display data in the 3 columns. This code prints the same date for all three columns.  I have a full report PDF, but this page needs to be broken into 3 arrays and printed. I took off all of my sample code as none of them were working. I would appreciate some direction with this, thanks.

```
<?php 
require ('conn.php');
require ('lib/fpdf.php'); 

// account or item_code for practice -- will be getting from a GET statment 
$item_code= 9999;
// query to get fields for top part of form
$info=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM practice WHERE item_code = $item_code");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($info)){
  $firstname = $row['firstname'];
  $lastname = $row['lastname']; 
  $street = $row['street'];
  $city = $row['city'];
  $st = $row['st'];
  $zip = $row['zip'];
  $name = "{$row['lastname']}, {$row['firstname']} ";
  $csz = "{$row['city']}, {$row['st']} {$row['zip']}";
}

class PDF extends FPDF
{
  // Page header
  function Header()
  {
    // Logo
    // $this->Image('sample.png',10,6,30);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Title
    $this->Cell(30,10,' ',0,0,'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(1);
  }
  
  // Page footer
  function Footer()
  {
    
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-30);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',16);
    $this->Cell(0,10, 'Thank You!',0,0,'C');
    $this->Ln(4);
    $this->Ln(4);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    $this->Cell(0,10, 'ADDRESS',0,0,'C');
    $this->Ln(4);
    $this->Cell(0,10, 'TAX ID 99-9999999 www..com',0,0,'C');
    $this->Ln(4);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
  }
}

/*A4 width : 219mm*/

$pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->AliasNbPages();


$pdf->AddPage();
/*output the result*/

/*set font to arial, bold, 14pt*/
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',20);

$pdf->SetDrawColor(180,180,255);

/*Cell(width , height , text , border , end line , [align])*/
$pdf->Cell(50 ,10,'',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(50 ,10,'',0,1);


$pdf->Cell(71 ,10,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(59 ,5,'TITLE',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(59 ,10,'',0,1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
$pdf->Cell(200 ,5,'2020 LIST',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(19 ,5,'',0,1);


$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
$pdf->Cell(130 ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(59 ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(189 ,10,'',0,1);

$pdf->Cell(50 ,10,'',0,1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
$pdf->Cell(15 ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(30 ,5,$name ,0,0);
$pdf->Cell(56 ,5,'' ,0,0);
$pdf->Cell(59 ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(59 ,5,'',0,1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Cell(15 ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(115 ,5,$street,0,0);
$pdf->Cell(25 ,5,' Account ID:',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(34 ,5,$item_code,0,1);
$pdf->Cell(15 ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(115 ,5,$csz,0,0);

$pdf->Cell(59 ,5,'Any Questions Contact: Don',0,1);


$pdf->Cell(130 ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(58 ,5,'don@.org',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(1 ,5,'',0,1);

$pdf->Cell(50 ,10,'',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(1 ,6,'_',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(190,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(2 ,10,'_',0,1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
$pdf->Cell(15 ,6,'',0,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(130 ,5,'Contributions',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(59 ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(189 ,10,'',0,1);


$pdf->Cell(100,10,'Check List',0,1);

$pdf->SetFillColor(180,180,255);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(180,180,255);

//   $pdf->Cell(10,5,'',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(15,5,'Date',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(25,5,'Ckno',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(17,5,'Amt',1,0,'R');
$pdf->Cell(10,5,'',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(15,5,'Date',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(25,5,'Ckno',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(17,5,'Amt',1,0,'R');
$pdf->Cell(10,5,'',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(15,5,'Date',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(25,5,'Ckno',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(17,5,'Amt',1,1,'R');


$query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM practice WHERE item_code = $item_code ORDER BY item_date ASC");
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
  $odate=$data['item_date'];
  $date = date("m-d", strtotime($odate));

  //$pdf->Cell(10,5,'','LR',0);
  $pdf->Cell(15,5,$date,'LR',0);
  $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['item_desc'],'LR',0);
  $pdf->Cell(17,5,$data['order_item_price'],'LR',0,'R');
  $pdf->Cell(10,5,'',0,0);
  $pdf->Cell(15,5,$date,'LR',0);
  $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['item_desc'],'LR',0);
  $pdf->Cell(17,5,$data['order_item_price'],'LR',0,'R');
  $pdf->Cell(10,5,'',0,0);
  $pdf->Cell(15,5,$date,'LR',0);
  $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['item_desc'],'LR',0);
  $pdf->Cell(17,5,$data['order_item_price'],'LR',1,'R');
}

$pdf->Output();

?>
```

[image: the report per the code]

Comment: You are using the same variable `$data`  in all 3 columns. Just change it.

Comment: why dont you use the fpdi wrapper package with your fpdf? it will be much simpler with less code. Just search "fpdi fpdf". The free package from Setasign works fine